# object id and youtube video id is the same with youtube_it gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, youtube, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using this gem to upload video to youtube from my app:

https://github.com/kylejginavan/youtube_it

This is my request with token:

```
{:url=>"http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/action/FormDataUpload/AIwbFATUMuFsv2GfJp4jkDXk3mkLNF6WklzOSoX05p96enTOMAj6DlnXpe1Rav-ZxZwNRrGC_7-8kStHFA2nisMb09CjdJgNBA?nexturl=http://localhost:3000/es/cvs/5152d31aa61654e56b000001/save_video?cv_id=5152d31aa61654e56b000001", :token=>"AIwbFAQv5ZE9-TBWTNNJi4Ng6_tvoLaxW0JVDCU7TE0rxiT_2CUFw-eZR5kuZr_0tkWBTtpWVu4I-OcfMsfnusqHYQNwq1EsVaCuGDnbqV07OwngagOQYXfzgnxwNzDJ5H1ESkRWKjtOVGGP1-ETDhDdB45-ZyYxlVQVKbitcrONJz1NKI4adqhVrPhmTJaKyjysb5mtWlNYoA1DGesmEwg6UG4y9Nwg1ekVYpi_fB8lvFE5CkchG1AhDkei6yq0wQSyxJVBbF3mhgFuh8ZSRvCuxRvKH7tTmx0ew3P9dmv61S5MQHs5_cwY-pGq4rce4xjVKBB68j5GoT6RaJxKbhLXrV6_pQwUACG40tTWxWhVHLZDneAlzDwnveFBJRE41xCI0G_sbkIJ5703Y1dLorXAGcjNxMFe3-MJ-zbPXWpyZeK7TD2s0lnbc6cdOPje8DGFAFmc6P_7TD6RzTepoBkOOhAokGKpAYkfxacBD77aaExHCzFHde-9jFNZQ2QelPL2YXwyMA8lcX81c3zItut1NKp1soXxuGDNkBPOpu2OzYuGTSBS9PPyvFfqUMHg5X2KDADn2uYNU25nDMIKJlG4VeCfntEbr1J0m1HpcFR3_8LK9hlehuHjqmY_7e8lIbSRJHmEEhw2bQG1aIh7gClZDVVfeJnA52r8Sb_7O4yWtkbii6
```

When I upload the video I get these params on my log:

```
{"cv_id"=>"5152d31aa61654e56b000001", "status"=>"200", "id"=>"5152d31aa61654e56b000001", "action"=>"save_video", "controller"=>"cvs", "locale"=>"es"}
```

Both **cv_id** and **id** are the same id, this is incorrect.

However in url I can see the **youtube video id**, this is the url:

```
http://localhost:3000/es/cvs/5152d31aa61654e56b000001/save_video?cv_id=5152d31aa61654e56b000001&status=200&id=GJUIN83LrdQ
```

The correct youtube video id is **GJUIN83LrdQ**

These are my routes with this resource:

```
Myapp::Application.routes.draw do
  #
  #
  resources :cvs do
   member do
    get :upload, :save_video
   end
  end
  #
  #
end
```

I'm using strong parameters gem, I don't know if this is the problem.

How can I fix this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the route definition for `/es/cvs/5152d31aa61654e56b000001/save_video`? I'm guessing the route matches youtube id segment the path as :id, as in `/es/cvs/:id/save_video`, which will clobber the id param in the query string.

Comment: This is the route for `save_video` action on `cvs` controller: `(/:locale)/cvs/:id/save_video(.:format)                          cvs#save_video` I have added routes to my question. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mismatch between your routes and the data you expect to see. Your route specifies an `:id` param in the path which will take precedence over an `id` param in the query string. Since the id in the path and the cv_id in the query string are the same (5152d31aa61654e56b000001) you see this value for both param keys.

Depending on what your options are, consider omitting id from the query string you provide for `nexturl` and placing it in the path param for `:id`:

```
http://localhost:3000/es/cvs/GJUIN83LrdQ/save_video?cv_id=5152d31aa61654e56b000001
```

Alternatively, rename your route so it specifies the `:cv_id` and omit `cv_id` from the query string:

```
# route:
(/:locale)/cvs/:cv_id/save_video(.:format) cvs#save_video

http://localhost:3000/es/cvs/5152d31aa61654e56b000001/save_video?id=GJUIN83LrdQ
```

Comment: Thank you I have fixed the problem with `resources :cvs do
      new do
        get :upload, :save_video
      end
    end` Thank you very much again!